# Azure Front Door to Website on IIS VM Host

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I've got an Azure Front Door that has been set up to link to 2 Windows VM's running IIS, I'm trying to add a Frontend Domain that I can then use to access websites on the VM's.
[Azure Frontend Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S33ww.png)

Then I have the backend pool which links to the 2 servers.
[Back End Pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4304o.png)

I then have a route to the web servers, which should (as far as I can tell) just forward the request onwards.
[Routing Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEiDn.png)

Then I have my web servers which I have set up the bindings on for the website
[Website Bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcFh9.png)

However whenever I try to browse to the website I just see the IIS landing page rather than the website I have setup. How do I get to my actual website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the end was that the Certificate subject name validation had been enabled. To change you need to go to Front Door Designer then Settings.
[image: Certificate Subject Name Setting]

Answer (score 0):

if you get the IIS landing page it means the traffic is forwarded correctly from the AFD, your problem is likely with the local IIS setup like the default page or something like that.